# How to Restrict Access to Maven automation testing framework Project's Main Folder Contents?

Tags: java, maven, security, access-control, project-structure

I have a Maven automation testing BDD-Cucumber framework project where the main folder contains essential testing configurations and reusable components. I want to allow clients to use these components and extend classes from the main folder, but I need to prevent them from viewing the implementation details available in main folder.

What would be the best approach or set of configurations to achieve this level of access restriction in a Maven project? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've explored various Maven configuration options and access control mechanisms, but haven't found a specific solution that addresses this scenario. I've looked into Maven's build profiles and resource filtering, but they don't seem to provide the level of access restriction I'm aiming for.

I'm looking for a way to configure my Maven automation testing BDD-Cucumber project so that clients can utilize the reusable components and extend classes from the main folder, but they shouldn't be able to view the implementation details within the main folder. This would provide a level of abstraction and protect sensitive information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow someone to extend a class, then you give them access to the implementation details.

There is no real way around that.

Comment: Thanks. I am beginer into this so please bear with my basic questions but is there a way by creating jar file of the main folder? Like we create jar or aar file in release mode which allows to use but hide the implementation.

Comment: Generally, hiding implementation is a difficult thing. Java Byte code can be decompiled, with often pretty good results. You can, of course, obfuscate the code, but that might lead to other problems for the users of the code. What is the reason you want to hide the implementation?

Comment: We provide frameworks to external companies for use in their projects. One of our key concerns is safeguarding. By hiding the implementation details, we aim to ensure that the core logic  behind the framework remain proprietary and inaccessible to others.

Comment: @DheerajKumarRajak Then I would probably take a deep look into obfuscator software. On the other hand, you should note that many companies don't like to buy frameworks if they cannot get the source code as well.